# Best way to handle webhook response timeouts in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, shopify

I have a Flask application running on a Google Cloud Function that receives a Webhook from Shopify when an order is created. The problem is I'm timing out very often, here's what I mean by that:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def connectToSheets(request):
    print('Webhook received...')

    # Verify request is coming from Shopify
    data = request.data
    hmac_header = request.headers.get('X-Shopify-Hmac-SHA256')
    verify_webhook(data, hmac_header)
    print('Request validated...')

    # Do some stuff...
```

Shopify's [docs](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/manage-webhooks#creating-an-endpoint-for-webhooks) states that there is a 5 sec timeout period and a retry period for subscriptions. After I validate the request, there is quite a lot of code so I'm timing out almost every time.

Is there a way I can send a 200 status code to Shopify after I validate the Webhook and before I start processing the Webhook? Or is there a work-around to this?

Comment: Possibly write a [background function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/background#cloud-storage-example) to handle the heavy processing?  I'm not too familiar with Google Cloud, but from the sounds of this doc you can have the background function be triggered by a Cloud Storage event.  May be possible to have the script in your question write to Cloud Storage, immediately return 200, and the background function be triggered by that object's creation.

Comment: See https://dev.to/googlecloud/getting-around-api-timeouts-with-cloud-functions-and-cloud-pub-sub-47o3 for an example as well (this uses Slack's webhook, but the behavior should be similar)

Comment: @DustinIngram that's exactly what I wanted thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it! I added it as an answer with more details if you wanted to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this entirely w/in Cloud Functions is to set up two functions:

- one that handles the initial request
- a second one that does the processing and then follows up with the response

In addition to handling the initial request, the first function also invokes the second function via Cloud Pub/Sub.

See https://dev.to/googlecloud/getting-around-api-timeouts-with-cloud-functions-and-cloud-pub-sub-47o3 for a complete example  (this uses Slack's webhook, but the behavior should be similar).

Answer (score 0):

I used to face the same issue as yours. So, we moved the processing code from being executed inline to be executed in a background task by using celery and rabbitMq. RabbitMq was used for queue management. You can use Redis for queue management also.

Celery - https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/index.html

RabbitMq - https://www.rabbitmq.com/documentation.html

Asynchronous Tasks Using Flask, Redis, and Celery - https://stackabuse.com/asynchronous-tasks-using-flask-redis-and-celery/

How to Set Up a Task Queue with Celery and RabbitMQ - https://www.linode.com/docs/development/python/task-queue-celery-rabbitmq/